# Booting from USB

Tags: 12.04, usb, windows-8

I created a bootable USB and booted from the USB drive, but I don't get the Ubunutu screen when the computer starts.  I get my usual windows desktop.  I don't get the welcome screen with the options like the instructions say is supposed to happen.  What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is windows8 then disable secure boot in bios. If it is other windows version after changing boot order in bios, while starting select the second option "Try ubuntu". Then ubuntu will be booted.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I have another problem.  I restarted the computer again, but I can't get the boot menu anymore.  I tried the ESC key while starting up, but that didn't do anything - it just started like normal.  I also tried F12 and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Upon startup/boot there is option a menu option or key to select the boot source.  What is happening is the boot order is probably CDROM and then Hard Disk and then finally the USB drive (or even a network boot).
If you want to change the order of boot, please go into your BIOS (typically F2 or F8 before WIndows starts to load) and modify the boot order (or it maybe referred to as startup order).